# How do I show Y axis as a decimal instead of exponent in plotly (Candlestick)?

Tags: python, plotly, candlestick-chart

Basically I'm trying to draw a chart with a really small numbers (e.g. `0.00000000045`). I need them to be drawn on Y-axis, but instead I get Exponent (e.g. `4.5e-10`).
This is my code:

```
data_for_df = []
for trade in parsed["data"]["ethereum"]["dexTrades"]:
    data = {
        'Date': datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(trade['timeInterval']['minute'][0:-1]),
        'AAPL.Open': float(trade['open_price']),
        'AAPL.High': float(trade['maximum_price']),
        'AAPL.Low': float(trade['minimum_price']),
        'AAPL.Close': float(trade['close_price']),
    }
    data_for_df.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_for_df)
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=df['Date'],
            open=df['AAPL.Open'],
            high=df['AAPL.High'],
            low=df['AAPL.Low'],
            close=df['AAPL.Close'],
            name="WRT/BNB",
        )
    ]
)

fig.add_scatter(x=df.Date, y=df['AAPL.Close'], mode='lines', name='Close price', line=dict(color="#ffb3b3"))
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title="BNB price",
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
    yaxis=dict(
        showexponent='none',
        exponentformat='none'
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[Input data](https://gist.github.com/apepenkov/d3ca47172e4a26518e8ffca808d9a445)

This is what I get:
[image]

without `yaxis` in `update_layout` I get that:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, found it. It shall look like
`yaxis={'title': 'BNB price', 'tickformat': ".12f"}`

My mistake:
I've precviously tried it as `"{.12f}"`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'tickformat' option instead of 'exponantformat'.

Like this:

```
 yaxis={'title': 'BNB price', 'tickformat':'e'}
```

Comment: It shows me an exponent (e.g. 4.5e-10), while I need numbers like 0.00000000045